SQL Server AlwaysEncrypted nvarchar incompatible
I want to use AlwaysEncrypted in a SQL 2016 Standard SP2 server with Entity Framework 6 but my query always fails with this error:

Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Operand type clash: nvarchar(11) encrypted with (encryption_type = 'RANDOMIZED', encryption_algorithm_name = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256', column_encryption_key_name = 'CEK_Auto1', column_encryption_key_database_name = 'MyDb') is incompatible with nvarchar
Operand type clash: nvarchar(11) encrypted with (encryption_type = 'RANDOMIZED', encryption_algorithm_name = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256', column_encryption_key_name = 'CEK_Auto1', column_encryption_key_database_name = 'MyDb') is incompatible with nvarchar

My database collation is Latin1_General_CI_AS_KS_WS which is not compatible with AlwaysEncrypted because it needs _BIN2. I have chaned the problemtaic column collation to  Latin1_General_BIN2 but it doesn't work.
UPDATE
I'm sorry but I forgot to mentiop that I use stored procedure for querying the from database. :| It returns a filtered row set and the total number of filtered records.
UPDATE2
The problem is not my stored procedure but the filter on the nvarchar column. When I run my select without filter is Ok, but when I put this filter ( where EncryptedColumn like N'111 222 333 444') on the encrypted column it gives this error:

Operand type clash: nvarchar(11) encrypted with (encryption_type = 'DETERMINISTIC', encryption_algorithm_name = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256', column_encryption_key_name = 'CEK_Auto1', column_encryption_key_database_name = 'MyDb') is incompatible with nvarchar

And if I change the 'LIKE' operator to an equal operator it returns with this: ... and nvarchar are incompatible in the equal to operator.

What is the query you are running? Not all queries are possible in AE

Are there triggers on the target table? It will be difficult for them to do anything when the AE private key is in possession of the client. Please Edit your question to include the full DDL of the table.

Randomized encryption prevents searching. That's explained in the docs:  prevents searching, grouping, indexing, and joining on encrypted columns. What are you trying to do in the first place? Do you really need Always Encrypted? Properly hashing and salting passwords is better than any form of encryption for example. If you really do, why not use Deterministic encryption?

Randomized cannot be used for joins etc, you need deterministic for that. It's not enough saying you're using a procedure, that's like saying: i'm driving a volvo when the mechanic is asking you for details on what's wrong with your car, just post the gist of y our query

If you use encryption to protect unhashed passwords, you aren't protecting anything. SQL injection or similar attacks on the client will be able to read the cleartext password on the client's side. Always Encrypted is used when you don't trust DBAs or the software between client and database. Protection over the wire is offered by HTTPS. Protection from disk theft is provided by transparent disk encryption (TDE).

Long story short, either use encryption_type = 'DETERMINISTIC' or find another way to do whatever you try to do. Which is still unclear

Thank you for your valuable comments. Yes, I realized I made a mistake with the Randomized encryption type. Thx I do not want to protect passwords but other data but the hashing is a good advice to consider. I am trying to protect the data of my program for GDPR reasons.

You can filter if you use parameters, but LIKEs aren't supported for AE (unless you use secure enclaves). Think about it this way, data inside encrypted column contains "gibberish" that is only possible to decrypt on the client computer, so the server itself doesn't know the values so it cannot do LIKEs. It can do joins because two columns will contain same "gibberish" so they can be compared by = (unless you use randomized, because then there will be some extra gibberish). When you use parameters, the client encrypt the values the same way so they also contain same gibberish and can filter

Yes, I realized the LIKE problem but I need it badly. :( Well, I think I try to solve my problem on another way. Thank all of you for help. <3

Btw, where EncryptedColumn like N'111 222 333 444' is just shooting yourself in the foot, because you can do: where EncryptedColumn = N'111 222 333 444' which should work with parameters and AE + deterministic. That's why you should post the original query

@PanagiotisKanavos Even with DETERMINISTIC either way you cannot do the comparison server-side. You must pass in the value from the client pre-encrypted as a parameter. The point is that Always Encrypted means the server doesn't have access to the en/decryption key so it can't do a comparison to an unencrypted value.

@Charlieface I don't know what the code is doing, only that it's doing something really weird. EF calling a stored procedure? It's definitely NOT for GDPR. That sounds like a poorly thought attempt to do privacy without actually thinking about privacy

@sada you don't need encryption for GDPR. AE does NOT prevent leaking phone numbers or other personal information if the wrong user uses your application. That's what Dynamic Masking is for, which returns the data masked for any user that doesn't have permission for that field. To actually implement GDPR you need to not retrieve inappropriate data to begin with, not display it in grids or forms, and actually perform role checks to determine what can be shown to whom. That's not much different from plain old role-based security

@PanagiotisKanavos You do need encryption, but for that you primarily need transparent encryption-at-rest, for which you can use BitLocker or TDE. It's just baseline security hygiene to protect data at rest, especially when it's at such little cost.

That kind of encryption protects from physical theft of the discs. That's a very, very rare occurrence. Far more common is theft of backups (including the cases where well known global consultancies stored unencrypted backups in public S3 buckets) which can be prevented by backup encryption. My point is that you can't just turn every encryption feature on and say you're GDPR compliant. That's not just lazy, it doesn't even cover the most common risks.

Of course, now that I think of it, if database administration was outsourced to a consultancy ... yes, you don't trust your DBA

That's the point.

You could perhaps use ENCRYPTBYKey/DECRYPTBYKey, although i'm not sure if whatever you're doing actually needs to be done. GDPR says nothing about encrypting data, as long as your DBA's company are certified and signed a GDPR agreement with you, it's up to them to handle it correctly. We also had some third-party hosting and data didn't need to be encrypted for gdpr-reasons. Although, we did own the servers, but they still had physical access to the drives. From what i remember of GDPR, it's more about purging old data rather than securing data access but i could be wrong, not a lawyer :)

I think you are right. As a developer I want to try to figure out how I could solve this task and of course GDPR is more than 'How could I encrypt my data?' question. I am going to broaden my knowledge I this area to find 'the best' solution. Thank you.
